# Configuring local registry with self-signed certificate

Tags: docker, openssl, docker-registry

I want to configure a local docker registry with self-signed certificate which i will be using inside my local network. I'm following instruction from docker manual [1, 2], but nevertheless run into errors.

Precisely, my problem is following. I create a self signed certificate on the local registry machine:

```
openssl req \                                 
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=openmpi-dockerregistry.local"
```

I put this certificate into `/etc/docker/certs.d/openmpi-dockerregistry:443/ca.crt` on each of the local machines.

Then I start registry and push an image there. Since I do not have DNS configured inside my network, I just put an entry into `/etc/hosts`.

Next I try to pull the image on the local machine, but this operation fails:

```
$ docker run -it openmpi-dockerregistry.local:443/hello-world
Unable to find image 'openmpi-dockerregistry.local:443/hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://openmpi-dockerregistry.local:443/v2/: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match openmpi-dockerregistry.local.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm very suspicious about message "x509: certificate is not valid for any names", which sounds that I did not specify CN correctly, but reading the certificate indicates the opposite ([full output](https://gist.github.com/planetA/83cad9b4c94fca0ff27d155c6bd287d6)):

```
 $ openssl x509 -text -noout -in certs/domain.crt
 ....
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         Issuer: C = US, ST = Oregon, L = Portland, O = Company Name, OU = Org, CN = openmpi-dockerregistry.local
 ....
```

Another option which I tried is to access the register directly by IP. I followed a manual[3] and added IP SAN to the certificate. Additionally I also set CN=*. So that the resulting certificate now contains following ([full](https://gist.github.com/planetA/e3cb41e5e402941881aa7f1857dd1320)):

```
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
               IP Address:<ip address>
```

But now when I try to pull the image I get following error message:

```
$ docker run -it  <ip>:443/hello-world
Unable to find image '<ip>:443/hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://<ip>:443/v2/: x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Although the file `/etc/docker/certs.d/<ip>:443/ca.crt` contains the IP address.

Could you help me to find a way to pull images from local registry?

*Update*

How do I start docker registry?

```
$ docker run -d \
   -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:$REGISTRY_PORT \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
   -p $REGISTRY_PORT:$REGISTRY_PORT \
   --restart=always \
   --name registry \
   registry:2
```

1. https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates
2. https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry
3. https://bowerstudios.com/node/1007

Comment: Check the logs in the registry container (`docker logs --follow $INSTANCENAME`). You'll see immediately if the problem is in the certificate. It would help to see the registry `config.yml`.

Comment: It says: `TLS handshake error from <ip>:44428: remote error: tls: bad certificate` For both domain name and IP address access.

Comment: can you share how you start the registry?

Comment: @jww Maybe you are right, but among SO, SU and U&L, SO has way more questions about docker.

Comment: @Stefano, please see update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't copy the certificate and key in the `/etc/docker/certs.d/` folder.

The folder should look like this:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/
└── openmpi-dockerregistry.local:443
   ├── client.cert
   ├── client.key
   └── ca.crt
```

In my case I had no `ca.crt` and it worked fine.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

---

I implemented your setup on my machine, everything worked fine after I copied domain.key and domain.crt (and renamed them) in the /etc/docker/certs.d folder. The only difference was that I used `openmpi-dockerregistry` as a domain instead of `openmpi-dockerregistry.local`

Comment: I do miss client.cert and client.key in the folder. Should I generate them somehow using ca.crt?

Comment: Actually they are the `domain.crt` and `domain.key` that you passed to your registry. For sake of testing I repeated the same setup on OSX and the story is similar but instead of copying the files in `/etc/docker/certs.d/`, I've copied them in `~/.docker/certs.d/openmpi-dockerregistry:443`

Comment: so client.cert and ca.crt is the same file?

Comment: as I wrote earlier I did not set the ca.crt

Comment: It finally worked. The caveat was that I had to restart registry every time I regenerate the certificates. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf to have the FQDN (openmpi-dockerregistry.local) and the IP address in the IP SANs list.
Add as follows:

```
[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]

IP.1 = <IP>
DNS.1 = openmpi-dockerregistry.local
```

Now generate the cert using the following command:

```
openssl req -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \                                 
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=openmpi-dockerregistry.local"
```

Check whether the cert has the IP and the DNS in the IP SANs list with this command:

```
openssl x509 -in domain.crt -text -noout
```

You should see something like this in the output if all went right:

```
X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:<IP>, DNS:openmpi-dockerregistry.local
```

Now copy this cert in the *client* docker certs directory in the following location:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/openmpi-dockerregistry.local/ca.crt
```

You should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out I did not add a CN or Common Name when creating the cert. I remade the certs, remembering to include the CN, restarted the registry, and recopied the cert over to the other nodes. This solved my problem.